# PHP and JS convert same date differently

Tags: javascript, php, date

PHP:

```
$start_time = '2020-06-23T22:30:00Z';
$timezone = new DateTimeZone("Australia/Sydney");
$date1 = new DateTime($start_time, $timezone);
$result = $date1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo $result; // 2020-06-23 22:30:00
```

JS (matches what I have set):

```
var date1 = new Date('2020-06-23T22:30:00Z')
console.log(date1) // Wed Jun 24 2020 08:30:00 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is the PHP date in UTC ?

Comment: @RiggsFolly, the trailing Z flag does not indicate Zulu time, but that it's a UTC time string - [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC))

Comment: @Klaycon Correct, sorry! However if you put  UTC time into js in a browser it will use the timezone in the browser to rearrange the date/time according to timezone

Comment: `GMT+1000`?? What? 1000 what?

Comment: @Klaycon— "Zulu", "Z" and "UTC" (and even GMT) are effectively all the same thing: zero offset. They don't tell you anything about the format of the string.

Comment: @RobG, quite right, didn't know Zulu was another term for UTC/GMT. the trailing Z is however a specific feature of the ISO_8601 time string to indicate a UTC string

Comment: @Klaycon—ISO pinched Z from [military time zone identifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_time_zones). ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing the timezone into the DateTime constructor will override the Z flag on your time string. Create the object without the timezone, then set it afterwards:

```
$date1 = new DateTime($start_time); 

// object(DateTime)(
//   'date' => '2020-06-23 22:30:00.000000',
//   'timezone_type' => 2,
//   'timezone' => 'Z'
// )

 $date1->setTimezone($timezone);
// object(DateTime)(
//   'date' => '2020-06-24 08:30:00.000000',
//   'timezone_type' => 3,
//   'timezone' => 'Australia/Sydney'
// )
```

Comment: smart. I've always wondered how I'd have to deal with dates if I ever lived anywhere other than GMT